# Best way to add include directories of root project to a subdirectory in CMake

Tags: cmake

I have a project with a `CMakeLists.txt` at the root, which includes a project in a subdirectory `test/` using [add_subdirectory](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_subdirectory.html) with the flag `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL`. The tests need all of the include directories of the parent project. What would be the most elegant way to do this?

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.1)
SET(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Modules")

PROJECT(autoffi CXX)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

SET(AutoFFI_VERSION_MAJOR 0)
SET(AutoFFI_VERSION_MINOR 1)

SET(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
FIND_PACKAGE(BOOST 1.50 COMPONENTS system filesystem REQUIRED) 

FIND_PACKAGE(LLVM 3.9 REQUIRED CONFIG)
ADD_DEFINITIONS(${LLVM_DEFINITIONS})

FIND_PACKAGE(Clang REQUIRED)

CONFIGURE_FILE(
  "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/env.h.in"
  #"${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/include/env.h"
  "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/env.h" # added to VCS
)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
  #"${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}"
  "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include"
  "${CLANG_INCLUDE_DIRS}"
  "${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}"
)

# The C++ interface
ADD_LIBRARY(autoffiCore src/Type.cpp)
# FIXME: boost package finder seems to be broken
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(autoffiCore boost_filesystem boost_system)
ADD_LIBRARY(autoffiBin src/BinFormat.cpp)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(autoffiBin autoffiCore)
ADD_LIBRARY(autoffiClang src/ClangEngine.cpp)
llvm_map_components_to_libnames(llvm_libs all)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(autoffiClang autoffiCore ${llvm_libs} ${CLANG_LIBS})

# The C interface
ADD_LIBRARY(autoffi src/PrettyPrinter.cpp src/libautoffi.cpp)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(autoffi autoffiBin autoffiClang)

set_target_properties(autoffiCore autoffiBin autoffiClang autoffi PROPERTIES DEFINE_SYMBOL BUILDING_SHARED)

# CLI Tools

ADD_EXECUTABLE(afdump src/dump.cpp src/PrettyPrinter.cpp)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(afdump autoffiBin)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(afconvert src/convert.cpp)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(afconvert autoffiBin)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(afcompile src/tooling.cpp src/PrettyPrinter.cpp)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(afcompile autoffiClang ${CLANG_LIBS} autoffiBin)

# Testing

ENABLE_TESTING()
ADD_TEST(headerASTDump afcompile test/assets/basic.h)
```

**test/CMakeLists.txt**

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)

project("AutoFFI Tests")

SET(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

SET(GTEST_ROOT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/gtest")
find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${AUTOFFI_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS})

ADD_EXECUTABLE(autoffiTest libautoffi.cpp core.cpp formats.cpp clang.cpp)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(autoffiTest ${GTEST_BOTH_LIBRARIES})
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(autoffiTest PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME runtests)
```

Comment: Using [`CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR.html) or [CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/variable/CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR.html) usually is less ambiguous

Comment: OK will change it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are keeping your main directory and your subdirectory test in completely separated projects. I suppose you are building test by invoking separately cmake and make a second time. No surprise that the `include_directories` of your main project as no impact on the test project.

You mention the command [`add_subdirectory`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/command/add_subdirectory.html), (that should be used to include test in from your main directory) but you are actually not using it...

Comment: Fair is fair ... this was the real issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `include_directories()` to add dirs, those should propagate down into targets in the test subdir. Beware though that relative paths are relative to the current source dir:

> include_directories: Add include directories to the build.
>    include_directories([AFTER|BEFORE] [SYSTEM] dir1 dir2 ...)
>   Add the given directories to those the compiler uses to search for include files. Relative paths are interpreted as relative to the current source directory.

[cmake docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3Ainclude_directories)

Comment: Strange ... I use `include_directories` in the root file, yet I get "header file not found" when compiling ... could you take a look at my config? I have added it to the question.

Comment: You should not make the subdir another project

Comment: _Typically the subdirectory should contain its own project() command invocation so that a full build system will be generated in the subdirectory_ https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_subdirectory.html Tried without, same error.

Comment: I guess it has to do with something else, I'll figure it out. Anyways, you confirmed what I suspected. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Found the real problem: was doing an `add_subdirectory` at the top of the file, instead of at the bottom, which was why nothing was declared.